# Setting a variable to the request's response

Tags: node.js, request, httprequest

I'm working in node.js using the node-rest-client or request libraries to make API calls to a service.  I want to be able to use let and scoping to capture the response however only can get the request...

In the below code when I console log newrequest it logs the request data, when I'm inside the function and logging info.check.id it logs the proper data.

var request = require('request');

```
var options = {
  url: 'https://api.pingdom.com/api/2.1/checks/******',
  headers: {
    "App-Key": "******************"
  }
};

  function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      var info = JSON.parse(body);
     // console.log(info);
     console.log(info.check.id)
     // console.log(response.info);
    }
    else { 
  //      console.log(body);
    }
  }

let newrequest = request(options, callback).auth('********', '********');

console.log(newrequest);
```

Comment: Return `info` from the callback

Comment: Putting return info or even a basic string in either the if statement or outside of the if statement before closing the function though doesn't alter the results of logging newrequest.

Answer (score 0):

At this point:

`console.log(newrequest);`,

The request has no response yet because the call has actually not been made yet. Due to node's async nature, the request will only be made after the line `console.log(newrequest);`. You will only be able to access the response in the callback, in fact, the whole point of the callback is so that you can handle the response.

Comment: that's what I figured it had to deal with the call back and the request not being handle yet, what's the best way of returing the data back though?

Comment: >what's the best way of returing the data back though. 

Where should the callback return the data? I assume this an API where you need to respond to an http request? If that is the case can you post the full code where you define the route handler?